# $.ajax Not Reporting Success Over SSL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl, same-origin-policy

I'm passing form data to a php script using jQuery's `$.ajax` call (CentOS 6.4) and the data is being successfully passed to the script and processed. The only issue is that the success message is not coming back. The connection eventually times out and is listed as 'canceled' in the console. I'm using SSL and both the source and destination are using https. The server error logs aren't showing anything I recognize as related.

Here's the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://theurl.com/form.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      $('#form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h1>Thanks!</h1>")
        .append("<h2>We will be in touch.</h2>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
            $('#message').append("<img id='received' src='https://theurl/processed.png' />");
          });
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('div#form').slideDown();
      },5000);
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And here's the only error that I think could hold meaning (though I doubt it, as I've heard this is indicative of illicit pings, but I thought the SSL may be causing it...):

```
client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.test0:)
```

Comment: I wound up having to just assume success because of time constraints, but I'd still love to know if anyone else manages to solve this.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything weird about ajax over SSL from the client side.